# Setting a bit after using realloc

Tags: c, bit, realloc

I am trying to fix my function where I set the Nth bit of an already allocated space. If the size of N is larger than the size of space malloc'd then reallocate more space to be able to set the Nth bit.

My issue is that whenever I set a bit higher than the space allocated it sets two bits. I have been playing with it for a bit now and I feel stumped. I feel like the issue lies with using realloc incorrectly?

An example is when I try to set the 52nd bit it results with this output:

```
0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Both the 52nd bit and 20th bit are set

I made a repl.it of my whole program here: https://repl.it/@dholton/Broken

More specifically here is my function:

```
Status bit_flags_set_flag( BIT_FLAGS hBit_flags, int flag_position ) {

  bits *phBit_flags = ( bits * ) hBit_flags ;
  int *new_data = NULL ;

  if ( flag_position < phBit_flags -> capacity ) {

    // Check to see if the bit request to set is lower than the memory allocated.
    *phBit_flags -> data |= ( 1 << flag_position ) ;

  } else if ( flag_position >= phBit_flags -> capacity ) {

    // The bit requested is larger so realloc new data to reach the length of the requested bit.
    new_data = ( int * ) realloc( phBit_flags -> data, ( flag_position / 8 ) + 1 ) ;

    if ( new_data == NULL ) {

      free( new_data ) ;
      return FAILURE ;

    }

    free( phBit_flags -> data ) ;

    phBit_flags -> data = new_data ;
    phBit_flags -> size = flag_position ;
    phBit_flags -> capacity = ( flag_position / 8 + 1 ) * 8 ;
    // capacity is number of bits

    *phBit_flags -> data |= ( 1 << flag_position ) ;
    // Set nth bit

    return SUCCESS ;

  }

  return FAILURE ;

}
```

Comment: If `new_data == NULL`, then there is not point in freeing it. You should free `phBit_flags->data` instead and set it `NULL` afterwards. Also when `new_data != NULL`, you should do `phBit_flags->data = new_data`, because it may be a new pointer. In that case you don't have to free `phBit_flags->data`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- the type used for storing the bits, `int`, is inappropriate: you should aither use `unsigned int` or simply `unsigned char`.
- the method used to set the bit is incorrect, see the correction below.
- the array reallocated with a larger size is not initialized to `0` beyond the original size.  You must perform this initialization yourself, after a successful call to `realloc`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
typedef struct Bits {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    unsigned char *data;
} bits;

Status bit_flags_set_flag(BIT_FLAGS hBit_flags, int flag_position) {
    bits *phBit_flags = hBit_flags;

    if (flag_position >= phBit_flags->capacity) {
        // The bit requested is larger so realloc new data to reach the length of the requested bit.
        size_t cur_size = phBit_flags->capacity / 8;
        size_t new_size = flag_position / 8 + 1;
        unsigned char *new_data = realloc(phBit_flags->data, new_size);
        if (new_data == NULL) {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        memset(new_data + cur_size, 0, new_size - cur_size);
        phBit_flags->data = new_data;
        phBit_flags->size = flag_position + 1;
        // capacity is number of bits
        phBit_flags->capacity = new_size * 8;
    }
    // Set nth bit
    phBit_flags->data[flag_position / 8] |= 1 << (flag_position & 7);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This whole block is wrong

```
new_data = ( int * ) realloc( phBit_flags -> data, ( flag_position / 8 ) + 1 ) ;

if ( new_data == NULL ) {

  free( new_data ) ;
  return FAILURE ;

}

free( phBit_flags -> data ) ;

phBit_flags -> data = new_data ;
phBit_flags -> size = flag_position ;
phBit_flags -> capacity = ( flag_position / 8 + 1 ) * 8 ;
```

`realloc` might return `NULL`, you check for that, but `free(new_data)` is
essentially doing `free(NULL)`. You should free the original pointer and set it to `NULL`.

```
if(new_data == NULL)
{
    free(phBit_flags->data);
    phBit_flags->data = NULL;
    return FAILURE;
}
```

If `realloc` does return a pointer, it might be a new pointer. If it's a new
pointer, `realloc` already freed the old memory and you don't have to do it.

So remove the `free( phBit_flags -> data ) ;` before the assigning
`phBit_flags->data = new_data`.

I'm not sure the allocation size is correct. Usually you allocate by multiplying
the required new size with `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof *var`. But `( flag_position / 8 ) + 1`
doesn't do that, in fact it isn't even a multiple or 4 (assuming the size of an
`int` equals to 4), so you might be allocating less space than you need.

```
*phBit_flags -> data |= ( 1 << flag_position ) ;
```

this is going to work only if `flag_position` is not greater than 31 (again,
asumming 4 for the size of `int`). So you would have to calculate in which byte
you would need to do the shifting.

If you want to have more bits than an `int` can hold, then you can allocate an
array of `int`s and use for example little endian in your array, meaning the
least significant bits should by in `data[0]`.

I don't understand you `flag_position / 8` calculation, where does the 8 come
from? If `flag_position` is 35 for example, then `35 / 8*sizeof(int)` would give
1, and `35 % 8*sizeof(int)` would give you 3, so the 35th bit would be in the
you would have to set the 3th bit of `data[1]`.

So the realloc should be

```
new_data = realloc( phBit_flags -> data,
        ((flag_position / 8*sizeof(phBit_flags->data) + 1) * sizeof *phBit_flags->data);
```

`(flag_position / 8*sizeof(phBit_flags->data) + 1` would give you how many
`int`s you will need, and `sizeof *phBit_flags->data);` gives you the size of an
`int`.

So the setting of the bit:

```
size_t idx = flag_position / (8 * sizeof *phBit_flags->data);
size_t bit = flag_position % (8 * sizeof *phBit_flags->data);

phBit_flags->data[idx] |= (1 << bit);
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, and for pointing out additional issues in my code!

Shouldn't I not free the existing data if the new_data == NULL? And just return FAILURE so I don't lose any data?

Comment: @David If `realloc` returns `NULL`, it's up to you if you want to free the old data. Depends on the algorithm. Sometimes you might want to return the old pointer and say "hey realloc" failed. Sometimes you might want to free the old pointer and say "failed, abort!". But when `realloc` doesn't return `NULL`, you definitely **doesn't have** to free the old pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
*phBit_flags -> data |= ( 1 << flag_position ) ;
```

should be something like

```
size_t pos = flag_position / (8 * sizeof phBit_flags->data[0]);
size_t bit = flag_position % (8 * sizeof phBit_flags->data[0]);

phBit_flags -> data[pos] |= ((typeof(phBit_flags->data[0]))(1) << bit);
```

Comment: I was already wondering why he uses dynamic memory allocation at all, as the size of the buffer couldn't exceed an integer.